# Creating Gallery Page/Nested Resource

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create  a gallery page that links to photo albums.  The albums work fine, but I am trying to pull the first image from each gallery_id to the gallery page.  I have a Gallery has many photos, and photos belong to gallery.  What I am getting is the first image loading for each album.

class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

```
def index
@gallery = Gallery.paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(6)
@photos = Photo.find(:all, :limit => 1)

end
```

def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @photos= @gallery.photos.all
  end
end

galleries/index.html.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Photo Galleries') %>.

<div id="galleries">
    <%= will_paginate @gallery %>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <% @gallery.each do |gallery| %>
            <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
                        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image), gallery_path(gallery)%>
                    <% end %>
                    <h4><%=  gallery.name %></h4>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

routes

```
  resources :galleries, :has_many => :photos
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seth, looks like you're new here.  Welcome.  Your question has some formatting issues, and I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish.  What are the models and their relationships?  You said a Gallery has_many Photos.  But you also mentioned Albums.  Where do Albums come into play?

Comment: You say "I am trying to pull the first image from each gallery_id to the gallery page".  Then you say "What I am getting is the first image loading for each album."  To me, it reads like you're getting what you want.  Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean album, meant gallery. what was happening is, i was getting photo_id 1 as the cover for every album.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is what you want:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @gallery = Gallery.paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(6)
    end
end
```

_

```
# galleries/index.html

<% provide(:title, 'Photo Galleries') %>

<div id="galleries">
    <%= will_paginate @gallery %>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <% @gallery.each do |gallery| %>
            <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                        <%= link_to image_tag(gallery.photos.first.image), gallery_path(gallery) %>
                    <h4><%=  gallery.name %></h4>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem in yours is that in your index action you grabbed ALL the images, regardless of what gallery they belong to, and then you looped through all of them in your view and displayed them.

Because of your association (gallery has_many photos), you can access a gallery's photos with `gallery.photos`.

In my example, I am displaying the first image for each gallery:  `gallery.photos.first`

If you want a random image from the gallery in question you can use `sample`.  i.e. `gallery.photos.sample`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use relations, which is what you need here. I tried to fix the code and added comments.

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @gallery = Gallery.paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(6)
  # You don't need the photos. You have to access them through gallery,
  # or you will get always all photos independent of the gallery.
  #@photos = Photo.find(:all, :limit => 1)
end
```

This is the view you are looking for

```
# galleries/index.html.erb
<% provide(:title, 'Photo Galleries') %>.

<div id="galleries">
    <%= will_paginate @gallery %>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <% @gallery.each do |gallery| %>
            <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <% gallery.photos.each do |photo| %>
                        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image), gallery_path(gallery)%>
                    <% end %>
                    <h4><%=  gallery.name %></h4>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you only want to show the first picture of every gallery, you have to change the view this way:

```
# galleries/index.html.erb
<% provide(:title, 'Photo Galleries') %>.

<div id="galleries">
    <%= will_paginate @gallery %>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <% @gallery.each do |gallery| %>
            <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <%= link_to image_tag(gallery.photos.first.image), gallery_path(gallery)%>
                    <h4><%=  gallery.name %></h4>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, however, this code outputs all the photos for a gallery on the gallery index.  i think i need to find a way to say find the first image where photo.gallery_id == gallery_id????